# Selenium can't press all checkboxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, checkbox

All checkboxes are checked first, after that I try to uncheck all besides "Киберспорт"
I don't understand why Selenium can't click some checkboxes..
I use this script

```
checkboxes = subpage.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-6 col-md-3 order-item')]")  # list of all checkboxes

for i, chckbx in enumerate(checkboxes):
    if chckbx.get_attribute("data-order") != "Киберспорт":
        
         print(f"{chckbx.text}")  # I get all names of checkboxes besides "Киберспорт"
         chckbx.click()
```

However, Selenium clicks not all checkboxes

Result is shown on the picture[image]

First 2 checkboxes in HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 order-item" data-order="Авст. футбол">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                                <input checked="checked" name="sports[]" value="20" id="sports_20" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="sports_20">
                                    <span class="custom_checkbox"></span>
                                    <p>Авст. футбол</p>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 order-item" data-order="Гэл.спорт">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                                <input checked="checked" name="sports[]" value="23" id="sports_23" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="sports_23">
                                    <span class="custom_checkbox"></span>
                                    <p>Гэл.спорт</p>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: you may not be getting the full checkboxes array... (DOM could still be populating...) Try adding a sleep to see if that helps.  If so, you want to use webdriverwaits and check for stale elements... (or just use a reasonable sleep period before getting the array of checkbox element references)

Comment: @pcalkins Problem is that i get all 38 checkboxes and using "for" I can get all texts I need, however I cant press on it

Comment: include the line where you retrieve the checkbox array... not sure if what you're targetting since the "data-order" attribute is on the div.  (might be better off filtering by id and targetting checkbox tags...)

Comment: @pcalkins  I added line where I get all checkboxes. I'm using Selenium without hiding a browser, so I can see how it press arrows line by line checkbox by checkbox, but It skips some... and I don't understand why..

Comment: could still be a timing issue... looks like something will add some event handlers since your click is working on the div.  (So dom still hasn't finished updating when you get your array... maybe not all event handlers populated)  Try the sleep and see if results change.  (still I would target the checkboxes instead and use the id to filter on if you can... otherwise use text/label of checkbox...<input type=checkbox>...)

Comment: @pcalkins I've already tried to use ```sleep``` method.. and it also doesn't work. I really don't understand why I use the same approach for all checkboxes but some of them couldn't be changed. I will try to use checkboxe's  ```id```, but I guess it won't help

Comment: see what happens with //input[contains(@id, 'sports_')   And using the click on those elements... it's also possible that the site is changing the DOM on each click, though that's not as likely since most clicks are working...(one change to the DOM would probably make all elements stale... and they'd all start failing...)  One thing that can help troubleshoot this is to try/catch your click calls to check exceptions.  Using webdriverwaits would also be good.

Comment: @pcalkins, if I find elements through ```//input[contains(@id, 'sports_')``` I'll get error ```ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable```, so I guess this is a wrong way

Comment: that'll throw for various reasons... but probably because the DOM is still updating (or possibly updating once one checkbox is clicked)  Did sleep help there?  Does it happen after the first click occurs?  If results from checkboxes being checked are returned without clicking a "submit" button you need to use another strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes has an id. It may be easier to search by the id. subpage.find_element_by_id('sports_20')